# Altering "posts_per_page" for defaut loop

Tags: loop

I am trying to alter `posts_per_page` value in default wordpress loop on-the-fly, not for a custom loop.

```
global $wp_query ;
// $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 1000 ;
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page',1000) ;
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    $wp_query->the_post() ;
    // other operations
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: What you tried to do won't work because the query has already happened at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom said, that will never work, as the main query have already executed. The only way to achieve that is to alter the main query **before** it is executed.

There is a action hook for that, [`pre-get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and this is the correct method to alter the main query.

Example:

```
function wpse_custom_ppp( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1000' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_custom_ppp' );
```

You can use additional [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to target specific pages